# Equation of a Pair of Straight Lines.

Tags: analytic-geometry

If $ax^2+2hxy+by^2$ be the two sides of the parallelogram and $px+qy=1$ is one diagonal then prove that the other diagonal is $y(bp-hq)=x(aq-hp)$.

By reading the question I just understood that the given diagonal is not through origin. Second diagonal is through origin and contains the mid point of the given diagonal but could not proceed further

Comment: Can you find out the points where they meet as sides and diagonal meet in 2 points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solve the diagonal equation simultaneously withvthe pair of sraight lines, eliminating $y$, you get the quadratic in $x$:
$$x^2(aq^2-2hpq+bp^2)+x(2hq-2pb)+b=0$$

Considering the sum of roots, the midpoint of the diagonal has $x$ coordinate $$\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}=\frac{pb-hq}{aq^2-2hpq+bp^2}$$

Likewise, the $y$ coordinate can be deduced directly by swapping $p$ for $q$ and $a$ for $b$, resulting in:
$$\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}=\frac{aq-hp}{aq^2-2hpq+bp^2}$$

Now you can write down the gradient of the other diagonal which passes though the origin and the result follows immediately.